# It is not possible to connect remotely to postgres from local only

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, connection

I can connect to my remote database from any server. But I can not do it from my local computer, shows a connection timeout error. It is not a problem of permissions on the host, in AWS I configured to allow 5432/TCP connections for anyone. It is also not a problem of simultaneous connections, having 0 connections I can not connect from my computer. What can be?

These are my [AWS inbound rules](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zir5q.png).

I connect using `psql -h host -d db_name -U user`. It also does not work with `psql -h host -d db_name -U user -W`.

The error is:

```
psql: could not connect to server: Connection timed out
        Is the server running on host "HOST_OMITTED" (IP_OMITTED) and accepting
        TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

Comment: What does `my computer` mean? Is there a route from `my computer` to PG instance?

Comment: My personal computer, which I use at home. I connect using psql -h host -d db_name -U user

Answer (score 0):

How is your security group setting of your Postgresql server on AWS? you have to make sure your local IP is allowed to access.

Comment: I assume they are inbound rules, right? @nickname123

Comment: Yes. It is allowing any ip to 5432/tcp and I can connect from any server.